# Gracefully catching Keras/Tensorflow out of memory (OOM) issues

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, gpu

I'm currently running some optimization / tweaking on different models using keras with tensorflow backend.

Unfortunately on some settings i'm hitting some out of memory issues which causes the program to stall out and continually list that the memory is insufficient.

Is there a way to catch this error, so I can log it and keep the program going?

The actually training is within a try/except block, yet that seems to not matter.

```py
#train and eval our networks
#this doesn't catch the OOM issues  
try:
    nn.train(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=config["batch_size"],
                    epochs=config["max_epochs"],
                    verbose=verbose,
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception on train", e)
```

Comment: You can't. Just run a smaller batch size.

Comment: Some more information about your problem would be useful, such as the architecture you're creating, what inputs you're using (are they images? Vectors?) and the hyperparameters you are using when fitting.  However, without further information and going with what we're seeing here as is, it's not possible as the out of memory error is created at a low-level.  You'll need to compromise and either reduce the number of parameters, resize the inputs if possible or even reduce the batch size.